# Can Telnet be used to test Direct Push is open "long enough"

Tags: exchange, cisco-asa, timeout, telnet, activesync

I am getting the event below in the Eventlog regarding [Direct Push for Activesync.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc182260.aspx)  If it matters we have a Cisco ASA and a Citrix Netscaler.

> Event 1040 MSExchange Activesync
>
> The average of the most recent heartbeat intervals [504] for request
>   [Sync] used by clients is less than or equal to [540]. Make sure that
>   your firewall configuration is set to work correctly with Exchange
>   ActiveSync and direct push technology. Specifically, make sure that
>   your firewall is configured so that requests to Exchange ActiveSync do
>   not expire before they have the opportunity to be processed.
>
> For more information about how to configure firewall settings when
>   using Exchange ActiveSync, see Microsoft Knowledge Base article
>   905013, "Enterprise Firewall Configuration for Exchange ActiveSync
>   Direct Push Technology"
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=3052&kbid=905013).

**Question**

Now you know the context, is there any way I can use Telnet to verify that the session is open for 30 minutes?

What should the telnet client connect to?  Is a telnet to Port 80 sufficient?

Should I set up a dedicated TCP inbound host just for testing?

Comment: You've adjusted the heartbeat settings and your firewall/netscaler timeouts to 30 minutes and are just wanting to verify that the message will go away?

Comment: I want to verify the functionality of the TCP session staying open. I want direct push to work, and also want the messages to go away.  So far NetOps has said everything is right on their end, but if I come up with a way of testing each device (Server, load balancer, firewall) I can figure out what is closing the connection.  Who knows maybe there is some proxy I'm unaware of